# How to disable input field?

Tags: angularjs

I have this input field that is black.

```
<input class="form-control input-sm bg-light-black white" style="border:1px solid #1d1d1d;" ng-model="gameType" ng-init="gameType='@Translator.Translate("ALL")'" ng-model-options="{ debounce: 500 }">
```

I made it that looks like dropdown so i want to disable option that user can click on it and enter something.I tryed with ng-disabled but it changes colour to gray.Any suggestion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try ng-readonly to disable input

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngReadonly

EDIT

Use `<input readonly="readonly" ...` if the value stays the same.

Comment: ng-readonly need some expresion? i want just to disable button always

Comment: It adds the attribut readonly="readonly". You can also set this in your html. If you dont change it anyway, then there is no reason to do it via angular.

Comment: it change color to gray then :S and its clickable

Comment: Not with the default styles. Check https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngReadonly. You need to check what style makes your input grey.

Comment: Better show complete html and css. Its hard to guess what you mean by: I made it that looks like dropdown

Comment: its okay now ... tnx :)

Answer (score 2):

`ng-disabled` will add the html-attribute `disabled` to the `<input>`-field which is displayed in a greyish way then. I think this is what you probably want. You could tweak the css of  the `<input>` field for the disabled state via css then:

```
input, input:disabled {
    background: #cff;
    /* custom style */
}
```

And to be complete, the html:

```
<input type="button"><br>
<input type="button" disabled><br>
<input type="button" ng-disabled="someTruthyExpression">
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the solution for your query,

```
<input type="text" ng-readonly="checked" value="I'm Angular" aria-label="Readonly field" />
```